# How to debug start of Chrome app / extension window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When you either start a Chrome extension or hit the reload button there is a delay between the app window start and when the Developer Tools show up. This causes the Network tab to be blank (even if Preserve log is checked) and breakpoints to be skipped.

How do you debug the start of a Chrome extension window?

I have tried the following:

- Reload the app with Developer Tools open
- Put a breakpoint in background.js and try to hit continue for the main window to start, but there seems to be separate contexts for the Developer Tools for the background script and the main window
- Restart the window by writing `window.location.reload()` in the dev console, but that yields error `Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://x/index.html#/overview"; try target="_blank".` ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751939/how-can-chrome-app-reload-itself-document-location-reload-is-not-allowed/30751967))

Comment: How do you create that window? Devtools has an option to auto open in popup windows.

Comment: @wOxxOm The window is created by chrome.app.window.create from background.js, might be able to set some devtools option when creating it and hope that the dev tools start early enough to debug the start.